# How can I use colour palette in Chakra UI?

Tags: chakra-ui

I am trying to use chakra colour system and I am new to the colour palette concept. Could you help me to figure out the following issues?

1. We had a brand colour e.g. "#1A838B"
2. And I went to https://themera.vercel.app/, and I got the following palette

```json
{
    brand: {
       "50": "#EAFAFB",
       "100": "#C3F0F4",
       "200": "#9CE7ED",
       "300": "#76DDE5",
       "400": "#4FD4DE",
       "500": "#28CAD7",
       "600": "#20A2AC",
       "700": "#187981",
       "800": "#105156",
       "900": "#08282B"
    }
}
```

My question is why there is no original colour "#1A838B" in the generated palette, how can I refer the original colour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem but I think when you are using coolors or themera and you try to create a palette, it respects some rules. For example between two-colour, you will need to have at least 30 hues of difference (this is some dummies value to illustrate those are not accurate).
So, it means that when you enter your value it will generate a colour palette to the closest to the one you enter and at the same time respect their own rules. In your example, if you check the colour of your generated palette "#20A2AC" is really close.

So, I know that this is not really the answer you are expecting but I think this is working in a similar way. If you really want your colour well, just replace it in the palette since the colour is pretty similar.